# Is it possible to animate an hidden property in angular?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5

I was wondering if it is possible to animate an hidden property in angular? Or do I have to animate opacity or height etc?

I want to create an accordion animation on my component.

This is the template part I want to animate:

```
<ion-row [hidden]="!open">
   <ion-col>
      <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Is it performance wise logical to use an `*ngIf` on an accordion toggle item? Like this:

```
<ion-row *ngIf="open" [@panelInOut]>
   <ion-col>
      <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

And in the component I do this:

```
animations: [
    trigger('panelInOut', [
        transition('void => *', [
            style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }),
            animate(800)
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate(800, style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }))
        ])
    ])
]
```

But this is not animated correctly is it better to use max-height to animate?

Could someone help me out on this accordion animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have list of animatable properties
https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/animations/animatable_properties/

so insteed of hidden, use visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reference :) Do you have a reference to a accordion maxHeight animation

Comment: No, but it is plaing CSS thats doing the work so use plain CSS.